# Auto layout - 5 buttons in center

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am trying to get into the Auto Layout business, but i find it kinda hard.

I am trying to get 5 image views to display next to each other in the center of the view. They need to resize themselves to expand their height / width as well.

This is how it looks in IB (and kinda the way it needs to look when running the app):
[image: IB Of views]

So i have the following constraints:

- Added aspect ratio of 1:1 so that they will always be squared
- First button is "hugging" the left side of the view, so it will be displayed in the side.
- The following 4 buttons have a horizontal spacing to the button next to them
- Each button has a constraint to the top and bottom of the screen, so they will get bigger if you resize the screen.

However, when i run it, it looks like this:
[image: Results]

And i am just kinda stumped here. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Best Regards - /JBJ

** EDIT **
I added a trailing constraint to the last button. This makes sure they are all within the screen, but is kinda problematic when thinking about the size of it, so that didn't solve it either.
[image: added trailing to last button]

*** EDIT EDIT ***
Tried removing the top and bottom constraint since they are the ones forcing the size up. Added a vertical center constraint to them all. This won't work either. Displaying them very small (lined up nicely, but too small) and also comes with warnings:
[image: In IB]

[image: In simulator]

Comment: try fixing the Trailing constraint for the right most image view

Comment: I tried that, still doesn't work. See edit for results

Comment: remove the top and bottom constraints and just center them vertically in the view.  It is the top and bottom constraints that are sizing your buttons.  Let them be sized by how they fit horizontally.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. It just displays them very small, but also comes with a warning. See edit for how it looks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

OK, here goes...

1. Add 5 buttons to the view... No constraints.

[image]

2. Add horizontal space constraints between them all. Also add constraints from the first and last view to the superview. I've also changed the last constraint to 0 (notice the +306 telling me it's currently out of place).

[image]

3. Select all the buttons and (using the add Constraint button) [image] add "Equal Widths" to them all. Notice the orange dotted outline telling me they now all will have equal widths.

[image]

4. Now align them in the vertical centre of the view with this button...

[image]

[image]

5. The last thing to do is to go to each one and add the 1:1 aspect ratio. You'll need to add the constraint and then edit it to a 1 ratio.

[image]

Make sure you update the frames once you're done to reposition the buttons to their new constraints...

[image]

The preview screen shows this working at all different sizes...

[image]

Comment: But what difference does it make if i put them in another container-view? Why can't i just use the view that they are in now as the container-view? The constraints should be the same? And i believe i need this since i need to have them change in both width and height?

Comment: @user3625855 yeah, you're right and I was just thinking this myself. Forget the container view. You need to have four things. First button constrained to left edge. Last button constrained to right edge. Buttons all have equal widths. Spaces between buttons constrained.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help, but it still won't work. Clearly i'm missing something. I have these constraints:

Left-most button constrained to left edge
All buttons have horizontal spacing constraint
Right-most button constrained to right edge

Now, it needs a constraint on the Y-coordinate as well. I guess i could just take a constraint to the top on all of them.

Then i set the aspect-ratio to 1:1 to make sure they are squared.

But this won't work? Can you maybe show an example? I have no idea what i'm missing.

Comment: YAAAAAY!!! Thank YOU so freaking much! It makes a lot of sense when you did it, but i couldn't for the life of me figure it out! I salute you, and thank you for allowing me to get on with my life. Off to buy a hat to cover the bald spots now. :)

Comment: This was extremely helpful!  Thank you!

Comment: i need a help in autolayout of 5 UIView's horizontally with equal distance between them how can i do that @Fogmeister

Comment: @DilipTiwari use UIStackView.

Comment: @DilipTiwari UIStackView is the new preferred way of using auto layout. /the stack view creates the constraints for you. Use it :)

Comment: i know but i m using ios8 its not possible to me to upgrate it to ios 9 for support of stackview pls help me @Fogmeister

Comment: @DilipTiwari Oh... I see. Well my answer here shows how to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: but actuallly i m not getting correctly @Fogmeister

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177619/discussion-between-dilip-tiwari-and-fogmeister).

Answer (score 2):

For placing them at the centre of the screen vertically use

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraintHorizontal = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY 
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:self.superview 
                                                                    attribute:attribute 
                                                                   multiplier:1.0f
                                                                     constant:0.0f];
```

For placing them horizontally 
Button width  = (width of the screen)-(button spacing dimension)- (left distance)- (right distance)/5;

Same for height.
Initial left constraint for the first image view will be left distance.

Comment: was kinda looking for a way to do it in IB so i can get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

What I always do in such a situation is just simply think.
How much constraints do I need to 100% define the design? What should I write to tell someone on the phone what it looks like?

In your case this are the following constraints (hope I wont forget one)

- They are all squares (equal width height, not a value)
- They have equal size, just set it to equal, not to a value
- Horizontal spacing between elements and edge, set it to fixed size
- Vertically centered

Comment: Yea okay that makes sense. Just not sure about the first 2 points:
All squares, so equal width / height, not a value? This is the aspect ratio 1:1 part, right? So i just set the first button to have 1:1 aspect ratio and the other to have equal that?

Comment: @Fogmeister U wanted to add another view, thats why I downvoted you, but atm ur answer is the best so you got my upvote.

Comment: @Simon yeah I was thinking of a different centre align (where you centre them between two views). Anyway, I realised after submitting that I was wrong which is why I edited.

Comment: @user3625855 I suggest you delete all your constraints and follow the steps of Fogmeister

Answer (score 0):

1. Place 5 buttons vertically and horizontally center in UIView
2. Select all of them and embed them in a stack view
3. Change distribution to fill equally.
4. Adjust spacing in attribute inspector to make space between buttons.
5. Add leading and trailing space and height constraint to stack view. Also vertically align it.

[image]